# returning struct variable from function

Tags: return, structure

[getting error : a.c:25:29: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
     case 1 : data = insert( data,dev);
                             ^~~~
a.c:25:19: error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘struct Var’ from type ‘int’
     case 1 : data = insert( data,dev);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5m9h.png)

[for function insert error : a.c:47:21: warning: ‘struct Var’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
  int insert( struct Var data, int sda[]){
                     ^~~
a.c:47:25: error: parameter 1 (‘data’) has incomplete type
  int insert( struct Var data, int sda[]){

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofZUA.png)

Comment: There is no clear question here...

Comment: i have updated my question check the images and errors

Comment: i have updated my question check the images and errors